# I'm facing with one little issue can you help me guys? any advice appreciated

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3, uikit

[This should be portray asset image when "ask" button pressed. i wrote all things that i knew but it still show like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox0Zu.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask].

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image you posted, you defined:

```
@IBOutlet var ImageView: [UIImageView]!
```

but then you try to reference it with a lower-case `i`:

```
imageView = ballArray...
```

As a side note, even correcting to an upper-case `i` you'll get an error, because you've defined `ImageView` as an **array** of image views, but you're code trying to assign **one** image view to it (from your `ballArray`).